# Rabbitmq hybrid cluster aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-mq

I'm creating the infrastructure for a project that will be half on AWS and half on premise.
I got stuck on this problem for a moment: the infrastructure involves a rabbitmq managed on aws and a rabbitmq installed via docker on an on-premise machine which must communicate together as if they were in the same cluster.
The customer's wish is that if the internet goes down their LAN applications will continue to work via the rabbitmq on premise.

I tried to enter these parameters in the rabbitmq.conf on premise and it seems to have loaded them correctly, while the one on aws rejected them.

```
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.1 = rabbit@<endpoint>:5671
cluster_name = test
```

Can I somehow get them to connect?